# prove if 7n+4 is even then n is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I'm new to proofs and I wanted to verify that this proof is sound:

If $7n+4$ is even then $n$ is even

Since we know $7n+4$ is even then $7n+4 = 2k$ for some integer $k$

$$\begin{align}7n + 4 &= 2k
\\7n &= 2k-4
\\ n &= (2k-4)/7
 \\ n &= 2((k-2)/7)\end{align}$$

Therefore we have shown that $n$ is even if $7n+4$ is even

Is it sound to come to that conclusion using the antecedant?

Comment: Watch out for your brackets there. You don't mean $2(k-2/7)$ - you mean $2((k-2)/7)$

Comment: You should mention how you know that dividing by $7$ won't eliminate the factor of $2$.

Comment: Your proof is invalid because you have to show that n=2 * some integer. You have not shown that $\frac{k-2}{7}$ is an integer.

Comment: maybe you could try something else.  How about contrapositive

Comment: Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by the $7$ is not OK when working in the integers.

Hint. Your second line is good. What could you conclude if $n$ were odd?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proof by contradiction. Suppose $n=2k+1$ then $7(2k+1)+4$ is supposed to be even. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

$7n+4$ is even $ \rightarrow$ $ 7n= 7n-4$ is even,

since $7n +4 =2k;$

$7n = 2(k-2).$

Now: $7n$ is even:

$7n =2r$  $\rightarrow$ $2$ divides $7n.$

$2$ is a prime.

Theorem in Number Theory:

If $p$, a prime number, divides $ab$,

then $p$ divides $a,$ or $p$ divides $b.$

$\rightarrow:$

For this problem:

$2$ divides $7n$, and $2$ does not divide $7,$

$2$ divides $n$, I.e. $n$ is even